# Tag merge: QUESTS -> SKYRIM

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-merging

As part of the tag cleanup from last year - I have removed 'quests' from all questions that *are not* Skyrim - can we merge [quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quests) with [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) to get rid of [quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quests) please?

**Important note**: before actioning this, I have flagged a variety of questions I could not remove the [quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quests) tag from - these should be edited before merging the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you have it.